# Converting a JPG image to PNG

Tags: r

I have a bunch of images in JPG format (e.g. myImage.jpg) that I would like to convert to a PNG format (e.g. myImage.png). Is there a way to achieve this using R?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You'll just make the file size bigger, without any improvement in picture quality.

Answer (score 5):

yes you can do that to transform png to jpg :

```
library(png)
 img <- readPNG("test.png")
library("jpeg")
writeJPEG(img, target = "Converted.jpeg", quality = 1)
```

and to transform jpg to png :

```
library("jpeg")
img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "img.jpg", package="jpeg"))
library(png)
writePNG(img)
```

Comment: Not sure why are you using system.file instead of just using the filename directly. Anyways, it works perfectly without it.