# Lossless jpeg in R

Tags: r, image

I have initiated a private project in which I wish to use the DDSM (Mammography Database) to identify breast cancer cases using Deep Convolutional Networks. The DDSM database is quite old and therefore contains image files in [lossless jpeg format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG). Is there any R-package that can handle that format. By handling I mean read and convert to another format (e.g. jpeg, png or raw).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a JPG image to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779804/converting-a-jpg-image-to-png)

Comment: seems hard.  https://github.com/team-charls/charls would be a starting point for building your own ...

Comment: don't think this is a dupe; following the link, it looks like lossless JPG (JPEG-LS) is a very specific (and obscure) format, not compatible with ordinary JPG